# Move the data range and adding another date at the end

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table as below and I would like my macro to change the data range after the code is released, e.g. as it is now 2020-11: 2021-11 to 2020-12: 2021-12. I would like it to do this by copying the range AI:AT and pasting to AH and adding a new date in the AT field. I have a macro that adds a consecutive date, but I don't know how to successfully copy and paste the date without deleting it.

Table what I have:
[image]

What I expect
[image]

My code what i have

```vb
With wbMe.Worksheets("input_6")
   .Range("AI1").Delete xlShiftToLeft
   .Range("AT1").Value = DateAdd("m", 1, .Range("AI26").Value)
End With
```

Comment: For me i see correctly. What is wrong?

Comment: Well what *is* wrong?  You haven't told us what happens when you run your code, and how that's different from what you wanted?

Comment: You are deleting cell AI1, but the second screenshot shows that AH1 is changed - that doesn't match your code.  Also don't you want to add a month to AS1 - why AI26 ?

Comment: @TimWilliams seconde i did manually , its just show what i expect, i would like not deleting but i dont know how to change my macro

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to increase each header value by one month:

```vb
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Range("AH1:AT1").Cells
    c.Value = DateAdd("m", 1, c.Value)
Next c
```

Comment: My main assumption is every time you release the code doing a new annual range.  For example, if it lets go now, it will be 2020-12: 2021-12 next time 2021-01-2022-01.  I don't know if I expressed myself well before

Comment: That should work then?